# How to calculate selected Excel range using ExcelDnaUtil.Application selection?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I'm writing a custom Excel add-in that assigns specific keyboard shortcuts to tasks such as number formatting for selected cells only. When I try to add a shortcut that will recalculate the selected range only, the entire sheet is re-calculated.

```
 public class Main : IExcelAddIn
    {

        public void AutoOpen()
        {
            dynamic app = ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
            app.OnKey("^N", "FormatNumbers");
            app.OnKey("^C", "CalcSelection");
        }

        public void AutoClose()
        {
        }

    }

    public class KeyboardShortcuts
    {

        public static void FormatNumbers()
        {
            dynamic app = ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
            dynamic selection = app.Selection;
            selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0;[Red]-#,##0";
        }

        public static void CalcSelection()
        {
            dynamic app = ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
            dynamic selection = app.Selection;
            selection.Calculate();
        }

    }
```

The `FormatNumbers` method works perfectly but the `CalcSelection` method forces the entire sheet to be recalculated rather than just the bits I've selected.

Would appreciate any suggestions to make this code work?

Answer (score 1):

There are various quirks related to the Excel `Range.Calculate` call. You can find some good information on the FastExcel site from Charles Williams: https://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsg.htm

If the book is in automatic calculation mode, it sounds like `Range.Calculate` will recalculate all volatile cells on all worksheets.

Comment: Many thanks, Govert. I figured it out - the code actually works, but only if Auto Calculation is set to False. Your suggestion on volatile cells was the clue. Any suggestions on how to force Auto Recalc off? Application.Calculation = -4135?